# How to send data from js client to express server and then back to client AFTER server executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Currently, I utilize

```
  $.post('/getDistance', a);
```

in the client to trigger an event on the express server in node.
However, this works 90% of the time. Not like sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, but it works perfectly fine all the time for some requests/functions, but others it only works halfway. It triggers the server event, but then the

```
res.send(object)
```

placed in the server doesn't trigger the client AJAX listener.

Here is the code example of this not working:

Client:

```
function getDistance(doc) {
  theDistance = 0;
  var a = {reqID: doc, currentUser: currentUserData.Address};
  $.post('/getDistance', a);
  //res5.send(a)
}

var res5 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url5 = '/getDistance';
res5.open('POST',url5,true); 
res5.addEventListener('load',onLoad5);
res5.addEventListener('error',onError);

function onLoad5() {
  console.log('OFHDISHOIFDDSHOIFDHSOIFHDSIFSODFS')
  var response = this.responseText;
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log('here')
  var isError = parsedResponse['Error'];
  if(isError == "yes") {
    chats = [];
    displayErrorMessage("Error getting requests. Please contact us or try again soon.");
    return;
  }
  var dsm = parsedResponse['dsm'];
  distances.push(Number(dsm));
    distanceObjects.push(new Distance(Number(dsm)));
  console.log("New Cycle Test Value w/: " + Number(requests.indexOf(currentDistancingRequest + 1)));
    beginDistanceRetrieval(requests.indexOf(currentDistancingRequest) + 1);
}
```

Server(I commented out alot of this since it involved api key with something else that is irrelivant here, and I used an example that has the same effect, because its only the send that doesnt work with or without the extra code I dont show):

```
app.post('/getDistance', function(req, res) {
  console.log('THIS DOES LOG')
  var reqID = req.body.reqID;
  console.log(reqID)
  var currentUserAddress = req.body.currentUser;
  var destination; 
   var dataToSend = {dsm: "10miles"};
                    var JSONdata = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
                    res.send(JSONdata);
})
```

I have no idea why, but this works perfectly fine with 80-90% of othder times I do this exact format. It is no fluke.

What is happening is, the $.post(url, object) works to trigger the server event, but in the server the res.send(newobject) doesnt trigger the onload5 in the client(nothing is logged/happens when run).

When I change that jquery post to

```
res5.send(a)
```

Then it works with two errors.

The first being that it triggers BOTH the server listener AND the client listener. Even if I deleted the res.send() in the SERVER, the client ONLOAD5 still triggers, which is a problem as I need onload5 to trigger if and only if the app.post() in the server finishes running and sends the required object to the client.

The second error is, when using res5.send(a) in client, is on the server

```
req.body.reqID
```

is now undefined, as the a that is sent is in a different format/sent wrong or to the wrong place or something.

Ideally, I would like to figure out some way to keep the $.post('', a) as it is used throughout most of my app already, but if not how would I solve those two issues using res5.send() in the client, or if anyone has a completely new easier way that can achieve the desired purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: You need the req.send on the client, otherwise the request will not be sent. The load event will be triggered on success (http code 200). Also you seems to be mixing jquery and xhr. Jquery post will not trigger xhr load event.

Comment: oh. That makes more sense, I think. To clarify, on client its req.send() or res.send(), and on server I still need the res.send()?

Also, how would I fix the other error of needing to get like req.body.element on the server from the res.send(object) placed in the client.